# Error uploading CSV to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I make table:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
date    date,
time    time,
val3    float,
val4    float);
```

And trying to load csv to it with next command:

```
copy data from 'G:\test\1.txt' DELIMETERS ' ' CSV;
```

the CSV have same structure:

```
date time val3 val4 
2012.08.10 06:53:18 695.417 773.29
```

But I am getting next error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "date"

Could you help me to find the reason of error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very used to postgres, but I think you should set your datestyle before importing your file :

```
set datestyle German, YMD;
```

Look at these links : [How do I alter the date format in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123484/how-do-i-alter-the-date-format-in-postgres) and [DateTime Output](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT)

Sorry if I'm wrong, but I think you have to correctly set your datestyle (you can also do in the postgres.cnf file).

Comment: It is better to use links to `current` version of postgres manual. `/docs/current/static` instead of `/docs/8.2/static`.

Comment: I had tried this command several times. It does not work with quote symbol. Plz look at my log http://postimg.org/image/51n25xr0z/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a header line in your CSV? If so, try

```
copy data from 'G:\test\1.txt' DELIMETERS ' ' CSV HEADER;
```