# Odoo 8, get error 'datestyle' setting

Tags: python, datetime, odoo

last night I was trying to learn about odoo and I was trying to get a date. I was successful at getting a date from another model and also I was trying to convert the date from `%d/%m/%Y` to `%Y-%m-%d`. But when I try to save it, The error occurs. I'll show my code and my error.

My code :

```
date_values = fields.Date(
    string='Tax Date',
    required=True,
)

new = datetime.datetime.strptime(get_date_from_another_model, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
self.date_values = new
```

Error :

```
DataError: date/time field value out of range: "23/08/2017"
LINE 1: ...iod August 2017', 'Faktur Pajak Normal', 4600000, '23/08/201...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

I was trying to find a similar question like this, I did find some question like this, but the answer is always talking about setting on postgresql, I think my postgresql is ok, but i think something is wrong with my code. I don't know, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

date_from = fields.Date(string='From date', required=True,default=lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

did you tried this

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: may be datestyle format mismatched you postgres, please verify this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123484/how-do-i-alter-the-date-format-in-postgres]