# Mapping with two tables using Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,

**Table_1 contains like,**

```
Project_name    Date          value
P1              15/06/2016
P2              25/04/2017
P3              18/06/2017
P4              12/05/2017
```

**Table_2 contains like,**

```
Name      Occ_June_2016  Occ_April_2017 Occ_May_2017  Occ_June_2017  
P1          8.1               7.5           6.5          8.2
P2          8.3               7.4           6.0          8.5
P3          8.6               7.1           6.1          8.1
P4          8.8               7.9           6.8          8.9
```

I want to get the value, based on mapping the project_name and the date.

Here is what i have tried.
Converting table_1 date column to a particular format,

```
 SELECT to_char(to_date(a.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'mon_YYYY') from table_1 a ;
```

**Output I  got as,**

```
jun_2016
apr_2017
jun_2017
may_2017
```

By using output above i want to search the column in table_2 by matching the column and name,

Am trying to get the columns based on partial match condition,

```
select column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS as c where c.TABLE_NAME = 'table_2' and c.COLUMN_NAME like '%occ_%';
```

Here is the output for the above query,

```
Occ_June_2016  
Occ_April_2017 
Occ_May_2017  
Occ_June_2017
```

Now i need to take the output of one query to the input of one query
Here is where am stucked. Mapping the date based on name.

**My output should be like,**

```
Project_name    Date            value
P1              15/06/2016      8.1
P2              25/04/2017      7.4
P3              18/06/2017      8.1 
P4              12/05/2017      6.8
```

kindly give me  a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a database function. First, lets create the tables and fill them with example data.

Creating and filling table_1

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (project_name TEXT, Date DATE, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO table_1(project_name, Date) VALUES ('P1','06/15/2016'), ('P2','04/25/2017'), ('P3','06/23/2017'), ('P4','05/12/2017') ;
```

Creating and filling table_2

```
CREATE TABLE table_2 (name TEXT, occ_june_2016 DECIMAL, occ_april_2017 DECIMAL, occ_may_2017 DECIMAL, occ_june_2017 DECIMAL);
INSERT INTO table_2(name, occ_june_2016, occ_april_2017, occ_may_2017, occ_june_2017) VALUES
  ('P1',          8.1,               7.5,           6.5,          8.2),
  ('P2',          8.3,               7.4,           6.0,          8.5),
  ('P3',          8.6,               7.1,           6.1,          8.1),
  ('P4',         8.8,               7.9,           6.8,          8.9);
```

Next, we create the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData(projectName TEXT, projectDate DATE)
  RETURNS DECIMAL
  AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    columnName TEXT :=  'Occ_' || trim(to_char(projectDate, 'Month')) || '_' || to_char(projectDate, 'yyyy');
    selectQuery TEXT := 'SELECT %s FROM table_2 where name = ''%s'' LIMIT 1';
    returnValue DECIMAL;
  BEGIN
  selectQuery = format(selectQuery, columnName, projectName);
  EXECUTE selectQuery INTO returnValue;
  RETURN returnValue;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The function takes 2 arguments. The first one (`projectName`) represents the name of the project (for example 'P1'). The second one (`projectDate`) is the date on which we want to retrieve the data (for example '15/06/2016').

We start by generating the name of the date column in table 2 from the the value of the `projectDate` variable. Once we have a name, we generate a dynamic sql query by replacing the `%s` placeholders with the values of the `columnName` and `projectName` variables respectively.

We execute the query and store the result in the `returnValue` variable which this function returns.

After we created the tables and the function, we can execute the following query:

```
 SELECT project_name, Date, getData(project_name, Date) FROM table_1;
```

This query returns the following result:

```
project_name      date       getdata
P1             2016-06-15      8.1
P2             2017-04-25      7.4
P3             2017-06-23      8.1
P4             2017-05-12      6.8
```

Comment: Do i have to put the above query instead of selectQuery there ??
Can you help out ???

Comment: No you dont need to do that. Just execute the first block of code I posted (The one that starts with `CREATE OR REPLACE` and ends with `$$ language 'plpgsql`).
After you execute that (that statment needs to be executed only once, because functions need to be executed only once) you use the `SELECT project_name, Date, getData(project_name, Date) FROM table_1;` in the format you want.
If you want I can post full sql example with test data.

Comment: LINE 1: SELECT project_name, first_move_in_date, getData(project_nam...
                                                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Am getting this error

Comment: have you executed the  CREATE function code block? 
Please try executing all of the code I wrote in the order I wrote it.

Comment: Show me the select statement you are using. It is different than the one I am using.

Comment: select project_name, Date, getData(project_name, Date) FROM table_1;

Comment: What is the `Date` column type in your table_1 ?

Comment: date is the type

Comment: Well I am not sure what could be wrong. Did you execute the CREATE TABLE statements I gave you above ?

Comment: yes i am executing what ever u created. That gives me error when i execute select statement.

Comment: As a last resort, please try creating a new database and executing all of the statements there. I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: is it because of this ( plpgsql ). Mine is postgresql

Comment: Mine is psql (10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-0ubuntu0.18.04))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174561/discussion-between-dvorog-and-venkat).

Comment: hey my date column has a format 'dd/mm/yyy', how to convert this into 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Comment: This question should be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123484/how-do-i-alter-the-date-format-in-postgres

Comment: It throws me error, if the project name from table 1 is not present in table 2 
Can you help me to sove that ???

Comment: It should return null in that case, not throw an error. for example: `SELECT getData('P5','04/15/2017');` will return null because there is no 'P5' in the table.